# Оптимизация парсера

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, re, parse

Какими методами можно оптимизировать парсер html страницы (1800 строк).
Первое что пришло в голову это:

```py
pattern = r"Link--primary.+(https?://.+)\"" # (регулярка работает если что)
preparse = # (тот самый html код)
for i in preparse.splitlines():
    i = i.rstrip()
    match = re.search(pattern, i)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

*Но дело в том, что выполняется код 8-10 секунд. Есть предложения по ускорению работы?*

БЕЗ bs4 ПОЖАЛУЙСТА)

Comment: `БЕЗ bs4 ПОЖАЛУЙСТА` - почему?

Comment: По своим причинам.

Comment: Хочу своими золотыми ручками)

Comment: Можно `re.findall` на текст без разделения на строки натравить. Или уже в `re.compile` уходить с поиском по нему. Пример html можно в студию?

Comment: https://github.com/phony51/GitProfileParser/blob/main/github.html

Comment: `re.findall` ищет все строки, которые соответствуют шаблону. А мне нужно найти группу(в моем случае сайт пользователя github). Не зря я же скобки перед _https://_ в *regex* поставил.

Comment: Мне кажется, можно удалить лишнее из этого html, оставив 300-350 строк или вообще вплоть до 50-100, а затем итерировать по нему и искать строки соответствующие `match`.

Comment: Вопрос лишь один. КАК РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ?

Comment: У Вас код разбивает строки, убирает пробелы, потом в каждой строке ищет. Это в любом случае дороже одной операции.

Comment: Вы думаете работу кода замедляет `.splitlines()`  и `.rstrip()`?

Comment: Все в комплексе. Когда Вы это делает в цикле. Так вместо условно одной операции вы делаете `N` операций. См. мой ответ ниже с тестом времени на 1к итераций

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код замедляет куча лишних функций: разбиение строк, убирание пробелов и поиск по каждой строке. Последние два в цикле. Это все можно быстрее сделать, используя один раз регулярку по всему тексту.

```
import re
import time

html = '...'  # Взял текст по ссылке автора https://github.com/phony51/GitProfileParser/blob/main/github.html

def find_pat(html):
    m = []
    pattern = r"Link--primary.+(https?://.+)\"" # (регулярка работает если что)
    for i in html.splitlines():
        i = i.rstrip()
        match = re.search(pattern, i)
        if match:
            m.append(match.group(1))
    return m

s = time.time()
for _ in range(1000):
    pattern = re.compile("Link--primary.*\s*(https?://.*)\"")
    e = pattern.findall(html)
print(e, time.time() - s)

s = time.time()
for _ in range(1000):
    m = find_pat(html)
print(m, time.time() - s)
```

Результат:

```
['http://index.php'] 0.008782386779785156
['http://index.php'] 0.09662365913391113
```

Comment: лучший, ++rep )

Comment: И Вам спасибо))

Comment: Все работает, но все равно долго, а причина крылась в том, что я кожу на телефоне и на 4 ядерном проце.

Comment: И ещё с плохим интернетом(вытаскивал html код через requests/)